# About: extracting *.gz files and move a original file to other folder

Tags: shell, centos, gunzip

I am almost new on shell script but don't know some commands.
I am trying to write below shell script , please give some direction.
    1. Read *.gz files from specific directory 
    2. Extract it to other folder
    3. Move a original file to another folder.
i can do it three separate shell scripts but i want it include one shell  script. Then this script will be cronjob and will run every 5 minutes.
    i was trying to start like below but somehow i am bit confused how to get filelist. I can do here another script but want to include in one script."

---

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read file; do
    gzip -c "$file" > "zipdir/$(basename "$file").gz"
done < filelist
-----------------------------------------
```

PS: Files are created in every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to implement what you're looking for (I would consider `notify`). Anyhow... this is a very simple implementation:

```
$ source=~/tmp/source   # directory where .gz files will be created
$ target=~/tmp/target   # target directory for uncompressed files
$ archive=~/tmp/archive # archive dir for .gz files
$ shopt -s nullglob     # avoid retiring unexpanded paths
$ for gz in ${source}/*.gz ; do gzip -dc "$gz" > ${target}/$(basename "$gz" .gz) ; mv "$gz" ${archive}/ ; done
$ shopt -u nullglob     # reset nullglob
```

If you know for sure "source" directory will always contain .gz files you can avoid shopt.

Another solution (not requiring shopt) is this:

```
find ${source} -name '*.gz' -print0 | while read -d '' -r gz; do
    gzip -dc "$gz" > ${target}/$(basename "$gz" .gz)
    mv "$gz" ${archive}/
done
```

The first line looks a little bit complicated because it manages source file names containing spaces...

Comment: Thank you very much, is is not gzip , it should be gunzip right for extract ?
and just don't understand shopt -s nullglob and shopt -u nullglob. (avoid retiring unexpanded paths)

Comment: suppose your "source" directory (the one containing the original .gz files it's empty). In this case the for loop will return the unexposed $source/*.gz (with the asterisk) and - of course - both gzip and mv will complain about it. By setting "nullglob" flag via `shoot -s nullglob` we prevent returning unexpanded (non-existing) path. The other command at the end `shoot -u null glob` reset it back this flag to its default.

Comment: re-gunzip: my command is correct because I did use `-d` (decompress) option ("gunzip" = "gzip -d").

Comment: Okay if i am sure about there is no empty files then can i not use shopt command ?